# How to programatically register a RoleProvider in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've implemented a role provider using dependency injection technique. So as the class doesn't have a parameterless constructor (a repository is injected there), the usual `web.config` registration method doesn't work.

I was trying to register the provider manually in my `Global.asax` application start event like this, but I get a `NotSupportedException` stating that the `Roles.Providers` collection cannot be modified.

```
Roles.Providers.Clear();
Roles.Providers.Add(new RepositoryRoleProvider(new MyRepositoryFactory()));
```

What is the proper way to register a role provider without it having a parameterless constructor?

Comment: what i did for my project is to inject into the Roles.Provider (not providerS) property. i don't know if is still available in MVC 5. for example using ninject I did something like NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);

Comment: @MassimoFranciosa Thanks for the comment. If I understand correctly you used property injection. Am I right?

Comment: EDIT: sorry, I checked and I'm actually still using web.config to specify the class. to achieve something similar I moved the dependencies from the constructor to properties. (just like you said :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article that describes [how to implement and register a role provider](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-role-provider/). It is using the "provider pattern".

Since it is using the "provider pattern", [it is not possible to use constructor injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern/) because the constructor is constrained to use a default public constructor.

So, your options are not good:

1. Instantiate your repository factory in the `Initialize` method (note if it has a default constructor, you could put its type string in the config file and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to construct it).
2. Use a static reference to your DI container (service locator) to resolve the dependency.

If you have a choice, it would be better to use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#rolestore) instead of membership, since it is much more DI friendly.